# Why did the Accountant's poor vision preclude him from playing soccer?

Tags: ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad, serhiy-zhadan

In *Voroshilovgrad*, when Herman and his friends played soccer against the "gas guys", the gas guys has 12 players, including their accountant (who they didn't let play due to his poor vision):

> The gas guys only had twelve players, including their accountant. Just like the apostles. You could say their bench was fatally short because their accountant, whom they didn't let play due to his poor vision, was their only sub.

Why did that prevent him from playing? Why couldn't he just wear contact lenses or something? (The text did indicate later that the accountant evidently did own glasses).

Comment: Glasses or contact lenses can't always provide perfect vision. For example I can see really well out of one eye with glasses, but the other is very poor due to physical defects. I am hopeless at ball  games. I am good at rifle shooting, archery, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That could probably be an answer.